# Not able to access Javascript from Ajax calendar control

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using text box and binding Ajax calendar control to it.
I need to perform javascript function on the calendar client click control, how is it possible ?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server"   Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtdate" runat="server" OnClientDateSelectionChanged=”function” />
```

I can able to view calendar without using OnClientDateSelectionChanged, but if am placing the OnClientDateSelectionChanged i cannot able to see the Calendar control on the textbox.

Comment: is this `OnClientDateSelectionChanged=”function”` exactly what you have in markup?

Comment: OnClientDateSelectionChanged="function"  its like this sorry for the above

Answer (score 0):

`function` is an reserved keyword in JavaScript and cannot be used as name for function. use this:

```
function calendarExtender1_DateSelectionChanged(sender, args){
    //....
}

<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtdate" runat="server" OnClientDateSelectionChanged=”calendarExtender1_DateSelectionChanged” />
```